# is there a tool that will let me take 'functional screenshots'?

Tags: html, css

It's one thing to grab screenshots of web sites and return to them for design and interface ideas and inspiration.

But increasingly I've found that when I want to examine something that previously caught my eye, the actual web site has since been altered, so I can no longer learn from the code.

I wonder: is there a tool available that would allow me to save interfaces in a format that would retain the html/css?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason why File->Save won't do? If not, you have your answer, otherwise that's pretty important information to know when suggesting a tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firefox. File -> Save page as..., select "Webpage, complete" and choose a destination directory. A file will be created, say `example-page.htm` with a directory containing other resources like CSS, images and javascripts in `example-page_files`.

Note: the HTML is modified to point to the directory with resources.

Comment: Chrome has the same save option.

Comment: The OP asked for any tool, so I utilize that freedom to suggest one. But you're right, every browser has a save option for a whole webpage. I've never tried it on browers other than FF, so I cannot confirm that.

Answer (score -3):

There are many places to view previous versions of a web page after the site has been updated. the web gets archived in a myiad of ways including user's browser caches, router caches, isp caches, search provider caches, ad tracking caches, third party caches, etc. Many are publicly searchable though none are perfectly reliable.

The two easiest resources to use are Google's cache and the Wayback Machine Internet Archive.

Comment: What you suggest doesn't help when one wants to present (usually unpublished) development snapshots like he wants to. Also, what's the deal with your shift key?